# Storing numbers to MySQL

Tags: mysql

Excuse ,please could someone possibly tell me what are the best column types for the following numbers?

0.021,-0.001

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need exact precision (e.g. when storing financial figures), use `DECIMAL`. Otherwise `FLOAT` should do.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

You should look over that reference. You weren't specific enough in your question to give a definitive answer, but it looks like, float or decimal types would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what those values mean in the system.  If I were to guess, I'd say you're looking for a fixed-point type, such as Decimal.  You have [several options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) with numeric data types, though.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. You can use flotaing point values like `DOUBLE` if it's alright not to have exact values.

If your values are between 0 and 1 and 4 digits long, you can also use `DECIMAL(1, 3)` for example.